# How to do update loop in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to learn more about using Oracle, and I'm trying to understand loops and how to use them.  I've got this :

```
loop
update table
set amount=(amount+3)
exit when amount>=20
end loop;
```

Currently amount is 12, so I'd expect it to add 3 to amount until it reaches 21, because then it will be greater than 20.  But the error I get is "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"  I've also got loop and exit underlined in red.

Am I missing something simple, or am I misunderstanding how to use loops?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on the update statement.  However,  there is no need at all to use pl/sql to do this

Comment: 'SQL command not properly ended' is referring to lines 3 and 4 line where you are missing semi-colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `BEGIN..END` block for writing  PL/SQL. For simulating your update operation through loops, you may use `RETURNING INTO` clause with a variable.

Although this solution is for your understanding, in real time it is not an efficient way to run Update statement in loop like this. It would be better to run a single update statement setting the final value.

**Note**: This works for a single row update.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
v_amount NUMBER;

BEGIN
 LOOP

    UPDATE yourtable 
     SET amount = amount + 3 -- WHERE clause
       RETURNING amount 
    INTO v_amount;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_amount);

    EXIT when v_amount >= 20;
 END LOOP;
END;
/

15
18
21
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  You're right that a single update statement would be best, this is a good way for me to see how I would do a loop if I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the objective here is to learn LOOPs in Oracle, yet the example chosen is not ideal. You may want to check about [ContextSwitching](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:60122715103602). Avoid issuing SQLs/DMLs inside loops as far as possible. Also never use PL/SQL to perform that which can be done using SQL unless it costs too much CPU.

```
update yourtable
set amount = amount + trunc((20 - amount)/3) * 3
where amount <= 20;

commit;
```

Instead, I would advise that a good place to start learning about LOOPs in Oracle in a structured way is using [OracleDocumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS00403).